# HttpUrlConnection returns 404 on trying to send data to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am making an android test app that just sends a String to server which is an instance on AWS EC2. However I am seeing 404 even though the IP is correct. What else can be wrong here?

```
URL serverUrl = new URL("http://aa.bb.cc.dd");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
String testString = "test123";
byte[] bytes = testString.getBytes();
stream.write(bytes);
stream.flush();
int retcode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

retcode is 404.

On the server side I have all sources allowed for the following in the security group being used:
All TCP, port 0 - 65535
HTTP, port 80

Comment: Unable to find url (404)..

Comment: Yes, that I know. But the IP is correct. In fact when I try on a specific port I do get a permission denied error. Also I have tried using Socket, and that works too.

Comment: Never mind. Issue was in my server code.